# .Net Core 3.0 Preview 5 Serial Sport Support on Linux

Tags: c#, .net

System.IO.Ports in .Net Core 3.0 works under Windows but not in Linux.

Has anyone gotten the new Sytem.IO.Ports functionality in Core 3.0 to work under Linux? (works in Windows)

I'm writing a simple serial IO program using .Net Core 3.0 Preview 5. The program compiles and finds the USB Serial port in Linux. (/dev/ttyUSB0)

The problem occurs when opening the serial port.

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600, Parity.None, 8);
port.Open();
```

I would expect the port to open and be available for read and write operations. Instead, I get:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'System.IO.Ports.Native' or one of its dependencies.